# ng2-idle hookup of mousemove event on HTML was triggering change detection

Tags: angular, ng2-idle

[ng2-idle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle) hookup of mousemove event on HTML was causing change detection and repaint of DOM elements for every event. Which also is blocking default click behavior of anchor tag (link).

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459183/2642351).

Basically called the set the ng2-idle's `setIdle` and `setTimeout` inside the  `ngZone.runOutsideAngular(...)` function so that the call happens outside the angular zone.